# How do I download a Bazaar branch without installing anything?

Tags: source-code, source-control, bazaar

I would like to download the source at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql-clr-team/connectornet/trunk/files/954. I don't see any zip options as I do with other source control systems.

How can I download the source of the latest revision or one specific branch? I would like to install nothing to do it.

Comment: You can't, is what it seems like.

Answer (score 14):

The answer is completely wrong! Loggerhead supports exporting Zip and TGZ. Just the location of the link is bad. Go to your **Repository → View Revision → Download tarball**.

There is a tiny bug in the code. Just add the line:

```
basename =  None
```

on line 146 (the `if` statement `true` test) only if your python version is 2.7 or higher.

Comment: This saved my life.